# I need to move all the contents from the top level site to a subsite. What is the easiest way?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have tried using sitemanager.aspx, but this only allows the 'move' or 'copy' command for subsites or individual items. And if I try to move an individual document, I get the following:

> ## Sorry, something went wrong
>
> File Not Found.
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> #### Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

There are just too many parts to consider saving each as a template.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, please check whether the document is well stored in the source document.

In addition, The Site content and Structure feature was deprecated in SharePoint in October 2018.

As a workaround, we could use PowerShell mentioned in below article to copy files between Site Collections:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-files-between-site-collections-using-powershell.html

Comment: "please check whether the document is well stored in the source document"
I've wiggled it around, and it looks to be well stored !?!